# DAX query with DISTINCT values, avoid repetition

Tags: powerbi, dax, distinct, distinct-values, analysisservices

I am doing a DAX query able to retrieve a list of products installed before a certain date (COIDate) , and that have a specific ProductLine.   But, it returns the same product multiple times.

I would like to know if there is a way, I'm sure there is, to write this same query, but specifying that, if a product has the same **ProductNumber** and **SerialNumber**,it's the same product and **must not be repeated in the results**, so it needs a sort of *group by(SerialNumber,ProductNumber)* or something like DISTINCT.
My background is SQL language, so the syntax needed here is different.
I tried just a distinct, like this:

```
EVALUATE 
    DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS( 
     'Analysis Services DB',
    "SerialNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[SerialNumber], -- 0
    "ProductNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductNumber] -- 1
    )
)
```

And it works.
Now I need to add also these filters:

```
 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductLine] = "TW",
 'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <> BLANK (), format('Graphics Installed Base'[COIDate],"YYYY/MM/DD") <= "2018/12/12"
```

This is the query that I have, that I am trying to modify accordingly to what I've said above:

```
EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE ( SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Analysis Services DB',
         "SerialNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[SerialNumber], -- 0
         "ProductNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductNumber], -- 1
         "COIDate", 'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate], -- 2
         "ProductFullName", 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductFullName], -- 3
        ),
     'Analysis Services DB'[ProductLine] = "TW",
     'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <> BLANK (), format('Analysis Services DB'[COIDate],"YYYY/MM/DD") <= "2018/12/12"
```

**EDIT:**
What I've added:
a query with a DISTINCT and a filter, but it's missed al the other fields.
Clearly there will be another way.

```
EVALUATE
        CALCULATETABLE( 
        DISTINCT( 
            SELECTCOLUMNS( 
             'Analysis Services DB',
            "SerialNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[SerialNumber], -- 0
            "ProductNumber", 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductNumber] -- 1
            )
    )
    , 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductLine] = "TW",
        'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <> BLANK (),
        format('Analysis Services DB'[COIDate],"YYYY/MM/DD") <= "2018/12/12")
```

Help me on adding the other fields, in the Select !
Thank you !

Comment: please add some sample data so we can test the codes...

Comment: Well, to test the code you must have the AnalysisServices DB, and it's very peculiar, because, since it's not a classical DB, I can't provide classical "INSERT" statement to test the data. What I am asking is just the logic, could be validated with any AnalysisServices. Thanks anyway for replying.

Comment: @RubyB you dont need to supply the original dBase. you can give dummy data and expected result with this dummy data...

Comment: @RubyB check my answer and comment if any...

Comment: @RubyB , if there is any data more than 1 result, you should assign one or more rules to have the result. Like latest 'COIDate' or filter on any other field etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
EVALUATE
DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            'Graphics Installed Base','Graphics Installed Base'[COIDate] <= DATE(2018,12,12) 
            &&
            'Graphics Installed Base'[ProductNumber] = "TW"),
        "SerialNumber", 'Graphics Installed Base'[SerialNumber],
        "ProductNumber", 'Graphics Installed Base'[ProductNumber]
    )
)
```

putting the FILTER inside the SELECTCOLUMNS.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your table but you'd need to think more simpler...

Modelling ---> New Table

```
Filtered Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    'Analysis Services DB',
    'Analysis Services DB'[ProductLine] = "TW",
    'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <> BLANK (),
    'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <= DATE ( 2023, 12, 12 )
)
```

[image: sample test data]

you need to have one or more conditions/rules to distinct the dBase... like latest date or any other rule on the other fields...

```
Filtered Table (Latest Date) =
FILTER (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Analysis Services DB',
        'Analysis Services DB'[ProductLine] = "TW",
        'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <> BLANK (),
        'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] <= DATE ( 2023, 12, 12 )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Analysis Services DB', 'Analysis Services DB'[ProductNumber] )
    ) = 'Analysis Services DB'[COIDate]
)
```

[image: latest date]

Comment: please approve as an answer if worked fine for you...